# Polkit / Systemd interaction

Tags: linux, systemd

I tried to add the following rule to polkit:

```
polkit.addRule(function(action, subject) {
if (action.id == "org.freedesktop.systemd1.manage-units") {
    polkit.log("action=" + action)
    polkit.log("subject=" + subject)
    polkit.log("unit="+action.lookup("unit"))
    polkit.log("verb="+action.lookup("verb"))
    if (action.lookup("unit") == "jira.service" ||
        action.lookup("unit") == "bamboo.service" ||
        action.lookup("unit") == "bitbucket.service") {
        var verb = action.lookup("verb");
        if (verb == "start" || verb == "stop" || verb == "restart") {
            polkit.log("returning YES")
            return polkit.Result.YES;
        }
    }
}
polkit.log("returning NO") });
```

When I run:

```
systemctl stop bamboo
```

I get:

```
Failed to stop bamboo.service: Interactive authentication required.
```

And the /var/log/secure file has the following lines:

```
Apr 12 11:19:00 myhost polkitd[1081]: Registered Authentication Agent for unix-process:22681:1068941302 (system bus name :1.192164 [/usr/bin/pkttyagent --notify-fd 5 --fallback], object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale en_US.UTF-8)
Apr 12 11:19:00 myhost polkitd[1081]: /etc/polkit-1/rules.d/10-buildsys-mgmt.rules:3: action=[Action id='org.freedesktop.systemd1.manage-units']
Apr 12 11:19:00 myhost polkitd[1081]: /etc/polkit-1/rules.d/10-buildsys-mgmt.rules:4: subject=[Subject pid=22681 user='myuser' groups=wheel,cvsgrp, seat='' session='' local=false active=false]
Apr 12 11:19:00 myhost polkitd[1081]: /etc/polkit-1/rules.d/10-buildsys-mgmt.rules:5: unit=undefined
Apr 12 11:19:00 myhost polkitd[1081]: /etc/polkit-1/rules.d/10-buildsys-mgmt.rules:6: verb=undefined
Apr 12 11:19:00 myhost polkitd[1081]: /etc/polkit-1/rules.d/10-buildsys-mgmt.rules:17: returning NO
Apr 12 11:19:00 myhost polkitd[1081]: Unregistered Authentication Agent for unix-process:22681:1068941302 (system bus name :1.192164, object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale en_US.UTF-8) (disconnected from bus)
```

The important part is that the action object doesn't seem to have keys defined for "unit" or "verb".  I cribbed this rule from here: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Polkit#Allow_management_of_individual_systemd_units_by_regular_users

Comment: Any progress on this?

Answer (score 2):

This functionality was committed here: https://github.com/systemd/systemd/commit/88ced61bf9673407f4b15bf51b1b408fd78c149d
and is available after and including systemd version 226. So it may not be available yet for your distro. RedHat 7 has currently systemd v219.

I too want this, and am currently opening a request ticket to RedHat.